# How to reconcile Amos 3:7 and Matthew 24:36?

Tags: matthew, amos

> Matthew 24:36
> "But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.

> Amos 3:7
> Surely the Sovereign LORD does nothing without revealing his plan to his servants the prophets.

Does this mean that one of these days as it gets closer and closer, the Father will tell his prophets the exact day of Jesus' 2nd coming?

Comment: There are a number of questions about this. One possible duplicate is [What does it mean ...  did not know the hour ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19249/what-does-it-mean-that-the-son-did-not-know-the-hour-of-his-return-in-matthew-24). Also [How do Trinitarians ... etc etc ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/41560/how-do-trinitarians-deal-with-mark-1332-in-regards-to-the-holy-spirit/41586#41586).

Comment: That the end of the world has indeed been *prophesied*; but, with the exception of Daniel, no other Jewish prophet has ever *dated* his visions.

Comment: What does there need to be any reconciliation?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "of that day and hour knows no man" is a Hebraic idiom that referred to the Feast of Trumpets on the 1st of Tishri.  Because the feast was held on the first day of the month, they could not know in advance which day would be sanctified by the Council.  So, they had to wait for the Council (Sanhedrin) to sanctify it after having the report of the two witnesses for the new moon.

That is why the Jews had to plan the feast in advance, so the Council declared the first day of the new month, then they could begin the feast.

Reading and understanding the English words does not covey the imagery of the Hebrew customs and feast days.  But, when Christ said those words to His disciples they immediately associated the warnings for the destruction of the temple with the Feast of Trumpets on the first of Tishri because they recognized the language of the feast day.

Contrary to what most English reading students of the Bible believe, Christ told His disciples the time of His return. He returned in judgment against those who had crucified Him, and were persecuting His saints in the destruction of that city and temple which had become desolate in the 1st century AD, specifically AD 70.

Matt. 24 was discussing the destruction of the temple, not the end of the world!

So, there is no reconciliation necessary with Amos 3:7.  The prophets and Christ told them what to expect.  They didn't know which year that judgment was coming, but they knew the time.  They knew the "last trump" associated with the last trump of the Feast of Trumpets was judgment day, also called Yom Hadin.  First of Tishri.

Christ did not leave them guessing.  See more scriptural proofs in the posts at my blog, ShreddingTheVeil.org:

Signs of the Feasts- Part I: Christ Told the Pharisees...[here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/17/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-i-christ-told-the-pharisees-the-time-of-his-return/)

Signs of the Feasts - Part II: Christ Told His Disciples... [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

Signs of the Feasts - Part III: The Thief in the Night  [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/08/02/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-iii-the-thief-in-the-night/)

Comment: I agree totally with your approach to this answer. It can only be answered from a Jewish 2nd Temple viewpoint.